# Is this warning/error message important and will it affect future running of the code?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, openpyxl

I have a .txt file that is continuously updated with data. The code averages the data and then copies it to an excel file. It seems to be working fine except for the message I am receiving.

C:\Users"myusername"\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_10264\230105361.py:52: FutureWarning: Setting the `book` attribute is not part of the public API, usage can give unexpected or corrupted results and will be removed in a future version
writer.book = book

I guess the part of the code that needs editing is shown below..

```
# Load the existing Excel file
book = load_workbook(excel_file_path)

# Open the writer using the existing workbook
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(excel_file_path, engine='openpyxl')
writer.book = book

# Write the merged data to a new sheet without deleting other sheets
df_merged.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Merged Data', index=True)

# Save the changes and close the writer object
writer.close()
```

How can I edit this so that I do not receive the warning? Note that I have plots and potentially other sheets in the excel file which I wish to retain after executing the code.

I am able to get rid of the warning but then my plots and other sheets get deleted.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might have to rethink how your implement the required functionality. In pandas 2.0.1 any attempt to assign to .book will induce **AttributeError: property 'book' of 'OpenpyxlWriter' object has no setter** i.e., it's a runtime exception and not  warning